# TFLITE python example label_image.py How to run with custom SSD_Inceptionv2 Model?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use the TFLITE sample from this tensorflow github:

[label_image.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/python/label_image.py)

Which works as expected with **mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite** but if i used my custom model from **SSD_InceptionV2** it fails to present the results. I am sure i am getting the output data but i just dont know how to parse it.

For example the code from here [Using the interpreter from a model file](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#api)

works perfectly, when i print(output_data) i get:

> [[[-0.07882401 -0.06323403  0.76715803  0.6412739 ]   [-0.05058636 
>   0.1590938   0.47510588  1.2784884 ]   [ 0.49940234  0.24378055  0.99502057  1.0976889 ]]]

if you compare both code samples they are almost the same but the **label_image.py** prints the labels with scores on this section:

```
 output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])  
 results = np.squeeze(output_data)

 top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]   
 labels = load_labels(args.label_file)   
 for i in top_k:
   if floating_model:
      print('{0:08.6f}'.format(float(results[i]))+":", labels[i])
   else:
      print('{0:08.6f}'.format(float(results[i]/255.0))+":", labels[i])
```

when i use my custom model (**SSD_InceptionV2**) I get the following ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label_image.py", line 94, in <module>
    print('{0:08.6f}'.format(float(results[i]))+":", labels[i])
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Variables Values with **SSD_InceptionV2**:

```
  top_k = [[0 1 3 2]] 
           [1 0 2 3]
           [1 0 3 2]]

 i = [[0.09889236 0.43745735 1.096226   1.0601109 ]
      [0.19237855 0.13102278 0.96343076 0.3539551 ]
      [0.09889236 0.43745735 1.096226   1.0601109 ]
      [0.4487209  0.25456518 0.993585   1.1151786 ]]
```

During the execution with tflite model: **mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite** the variable values were:

```
 top_K = [458 653 835 514 328]

 i = 226
```

As you can see the values are very different which i assume is because they are different models but i am not sure how to translate that to human readable output.